# How can I parse a string to BigDecimal without considering the leading zeros in java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this number that I receive as string 000000000007500 and I must pass it to BigDecimal not considering the zeros that are on the left, I have tried to do the following but the result is 0.0, if you could help me please, thank you very much.

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf ((Double.valueOf (transNum.getAmount ()) / 100));
```

Comment: What's wrong with `new BigDecimal("000000000007500")`?

Comment: leading 0's don't matter.  what is the value and data type of transNum.getAmount()?

Comment: General pro tip: if you convert from String to `BigDecimal` you **really** don't want to involve any floating point type (`float`/`Float` or `double`/`Double`) at all! Because you lose a lot of the benefit of BigDecimal that way (i.e. you first lose the precision and then store the lost-precision data very precisely).

Answer (score 3):

BigDecimal will ignore leading 0 in the `String` constructor just fine, so `new BigDecimal("000000000007500")` will represent 7500.

If you want to divide by 100 after that, then do it with the `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(transNum.getAmount())
                         .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), MathContext.UNLIMITED);
```